# Persistent Authoring with Breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've loaded a folder into Chrome dev tools for persistent editing (changes made in the dev tools can be saved directly to my local file system).

When I view these files in the dev tools however, breakpoints in these same files are not triggering.

I can place an effective breakpoint by opening the 'other' file in the Source tab (Cmd-O shows 2 files, one that allows persistent authoring, and another that allows breakpoints).

I would like to be able to make persistent changes in the same files I am adding breakpoints to.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this just the way it works?

Answer (score -1):

Did you map your network resources to filesystem?

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces see "mapping a network resource"